# How to correctly create a form to delete MySQL record by using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to create a form to delete the MySQL record. After checking lots of post here and other website, I am still confused about how to achieve it. Could someone guide me what wrong is with my code?

```
<?php
  $server_name = 'xxxxxx';
  $user_name = 'xxxxxx';
  $password = 'xxxxxx';
  $db_name = 'xxxxxx';

  $conn = new mysqli($server_name, $user_name, $password, $db_name);

  if(!$conn) {
    die("Fail to connect to the database $conn->connect_error");
  }

  $conn->query('SET NAMES UTF8');

  require_once('conn.php');

  $id = $_POST['value'];

  $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=%d", $id);

  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if(!$result) {
    die($conn->error);
  }

  if ($conn->affected_rows >= 1) {
    echo 'Delete successfully';
  } else {
    echo 'Fail to delete the data';
  }



  $result = $conn->query("SELECT * from users");

  if(!$result) {
    die($conn->error);
  }

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: $row[id]";
    echo "<form action='delete.php' method='POST'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id_to_delete' value='$row[id]'>
            <input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete'>
          </form>";
    echo "username: $row[username]<br>";
  }
?>

<form method="POST" action="delete.php">
  <label for="test">Username: </label>
  <input type="text" id="test" name="name">
  <label for="test">Password: </label>
  <input type="text" id="test" name="password">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean HTML form or the PHP code which performs the deletion?

Comment: Consider whether you really want to 'hard delete' data in this way

Answer (score -1):

I can see a couple of potential problems with the code:

First, you use $_POST['value'] in the PHP to get the $id to delete but you want to be using $_POST['**id_to_delete**'] because that is the name you have given to the html hidden input in the row's form (<input type='hidden' name='id_to_delete' value='$row[id]'>).

Second, the delete attempt will happen regardless of whether the form was submitted or not so you want to check whether there is actually an id to delete making sure it is a number.

For example:

```
...
  $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id_to_delete', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

  if($id!==null && $id!==false) {
    $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=%d", $id);

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if(!$result) {
      die($conn->error);
    }

    if($conn->affected_rows >= 1) {
      echo 'Delete successfully';
    }
    else {
      echo 'Fail to delete the data';
    }
  }
...
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: This is not production ready code! Do not use in a public facing environment! You will need to do a lot more work on validating who can post data to this php otherwise anyone could send a post request to the page and delete all your users regardless of whether they loaded the form or not.